# How to update and pull users using mongodb and node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mean

I want to update and pull users from an array using Mongodb.

I'm updating users in the array successfully and checking the length of users.

If users are more than or equal to 2, I want to slice the first 2 users and to remove the first 2 users from the array using the pull method.

example stranger chat connect (connecting two users when they pressed connectstranger button)

```
var userName = req.body.userName
connection.connectedusers.updateMany({}, { $push: { connectArray: [userName] } }, { upsert: true }, function (err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    connection.connectedusers.find({}, async (err, list) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        setTimeout(async () => {
          if (list[0].connectArray.length >= 2) {
            clearTimeout();
            var shortListed = list[0].connectArray.slice(0, 2);
            console.log(shortListed,'shortlisted array')
            try {
              await connection.connectedusers.update({},
                { $pull: { connectArray: { $in: shortListed } } },
                { multi: true }
              )
              const docs = await connection.connectedusers.find({});
              res.json({ 
                message: 'users selected successfully',
                status: 1,
                docs: docs
              });
            } catch (err) {
              res.status(201).json(err);
            }
          } else {
            const docs = await connection.connectedusers.find({});
            console.log(docs, 'docs')
            const allUsers = docs.connectArray;
            console.log(allUsers, 'allUsers')
            await connection.connectedusers.update({},
              { $pull: { connectArray: { $in: allUsers } } },
              { multi: true }
            )
            res.json({
              message: 'users not selected',
              status: 2,
              docs: docs,
              allUsers: allUsers
            })
          }
        }, 10000);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

The first post request returns `status 2 error : users not selected`, so I want to wait for some time. Once the array count increases to 2, I need to slice it and pull the selected users from the array.

Comment: How about you use Promises instead of async await?

Comment: I dont know how to use promises. thats why i used async wait..

Comment: Can you share a sample of how a user looks in your database?

Comment: You're doing the collection find immediately after your update and before you `setTimeout`. If you want to structure things this way, you need to find after you've set the timeout to make sure that the documents are in the window

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked, but if I were you, I might look into web sockets & how other folks have structured chat apps. This doesn't seem like the right way of doing things to me

Comment: And I know this also isn't what you asked, but If you're using `async/await`, you don't need to use any callbacks. You can do things like `const list = await connection.connectedusers.find({})`

Comment: The main purpose of using a database is so you can easily store and manipulate data and avoid having to do this sort of Array manipulation. I'm really interested in how you have things setup currently.

Answer (score 0):

This will wait for 2 secs using `await and promise` combo

```
let userName = req.body.userName
//wait till query result
let docs = await connection.connectedusers.updateMany({}, { $push: { connectArray: [userName] } }, { upsert: true });
//wait till query result
let list = await connection.connectedusers.find({});

//this will wait for 10 secs
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
     resolve(1);
    }, 10000);
});

//then process result
if (list[0].connectArray.length >= 2) {
    let shortListed = list[0].connectArray.slice(0, 2);
console.log(shortListed,'shortlisted array')
try {
    await connection.connectedusers.update({},
    { $pull: { connectArray: { $in: shortListed } } },
    { multi: true }
    );
    const docs = await connection.connectedusers.find({});
    res.json({ 
        message: 'users selected successfully',
        status: 1,
        docs: docs
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(201).json(err);
}
  } else {
    const docs = await connection.connectedusers.find({});
    console.log(docs, 'docs')
    const allUsers = docs.connectArray;
    console.log(allUsers, 'allUsers')
    await connection.connectedusers.update({},
      { $pull: { connectArray: { $in: allUsers } } },
      { multi: true }
    )
    res.json({
      message: 'users not selected',
      status: 2,
      docs: docs,
      allUsers: allUsers
    })
  }
```

Comment: `let sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);` followed by `await sleep(10000)` is cleaner and fits better with the async/await pattern.